# In update Trigger event does it also means trigger.new != trigger.old

Tags: salesforce, sfdc-metadata-api

```
if(Trigger.IsUpdate || Trigger.IsAfter) {
  if(
     STP_TriggerHandler.mail(Trigger.New);
 }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Your code contains syntax errors, please correct them.

Comment: hi Max,i'm trying to send a mail when value in a field get updated using after update event, and my doubt is after update also checks the condition trigger.new != trigger.old.

Comment: can you explain what are the syntax errors.

Comment: The second if statement requires a condition and a closing parenthesis at the end.